# Why is this css value invalid?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations

I'm trying to add a very basic animation and it works in jsFiddle perfectl fine, but when I try it in another project - it fails:

this is the element im trying to animate:

```css
.progress-status.complete {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;

  animation: shadow-pulse 4s infinite;
}

@keyframes shadow-pulse
{
     0% {
          box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     }
     100% {
          box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
          -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
          -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
     }
}
@-webkit-keyframes shadow-pulse
{
     0% {
          box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     }
     100% {
          box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
          -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
          -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
     }
}
```

```html
<div class='progress-status complete'></div>
```

why does it brake in Chrome then?
  [image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFXmm.png]

Comment: No showing as invalid in Chrome...but the prefixed versions should be **first**.

Comment: If you cannot replicate this issue with the code you have provided, the error must be in code that you **have not provided**.

Comment: this icon indicates invalid syntax and I dont know why. how could possibly another code make this syntax invalid?

Comment: Usually it means it's not applied because something is overriding it....but I'd certainly remove the `important` but that probably isn't the issue.